# Microsoft teams task module bot framework , submit task handler is not working

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

The task module is not getting closed at and not returning to the bot.
Inside my Customform.html

```
 async componentDidMount() { 
const { headers, } = this.state;
 microsoftTeams.initialize(); 
 microsoftTeams.getContext((context, error) => {
this.setState( { context: context, }, () => { console.log( "this.state.context in upn is ", this.state.context["upn"] ); } ); }); }
```

Submit Handler

```
     microsoftTeams.initialize();
     if ( reservationResponse.status && reservationResponse.status === 400 ) {
 this.setState({ showErrorMessage: true, loading: false, disableButton: false, }); } 
else { this.setState({ loading: false, });
     microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask( reservationResponse, "bot-id" ); 
return true;
```

The bot id is correct and the url in the list of valid domains.
I have tried every possible combination , but it is not at all coming inside the handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit  function.

Comment: let me check this issue and will get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

componentDidMount() is a react component which will not work in html file. If you want to call getContext() in html file you need to follow below code format.

```
    <script>

microsoftTeams.initialize();

microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context){console.log(context.entityId)});

</script>
```